# How much RAM uses by SharePoint services?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

In my system I have 4GB DDR3 RAM and I installed vm player and assigned 2GB RAM to that now I want to install SharePoint foundation 2013 in that virtual machine, So I need to know that

Is it possible to install SharePoint foundation 2013 on 2GB RAM ?

OR

If it is possible then how can I do this ?

Please provide proper solution on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "no".

You may be able to install SharePoint on a machine with 2GB RAM, but SharePoint won't work after installation.

As [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver) says, you should use at least 8GB of RAM to deploy a minimal Installation of SharePoint 2013 with every required component on one machine (ActiveDirectory, SQL, SharePoint).